# heap_corruption and system.reflection.targetinvocationexception errors

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I published my application in windows phone store and it has been downloaded more than 2000 times. The crash report shows more than 20 for two following errors:

```
Problem Function                   Exception Type     
heap_corruption                    C0000374            

wQuran.MainPage..ctor              system.reflection.targetinvocationexception
```

"wQuran" is my application.

Just to mention, I haven't seen any of these errors while development or testing it in windows phone 8 devices.

Any ideas, please ?

Answer (score 0):

For heap corruption, Probably you are writing beyond array bounds, or double delete something. Check all your news and deletes and indices when you are writing to dynamic arrays. Just having a delete for every new won't suffice. The logic of allocation and de-allocation should be faultless.

system.reflection.targetinvocationexception just means that something was calling reflection Invoke, and the invoked method threw an exception. Generally, this exception will occur when you trying to access a web service and it will become overloaded, or if too frequent WS calls are made, if the Business logic is complicated or db lock or unresponsive.